# How to report worker "event" in a client gui

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have been provided with a trial version of [parallel computing toolbox](http://fr.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) to make some tests and see how it works.

Among the tests I wanted to perform is to see how this toolbox could be used to run some background processing from within a GUI and report for processing progression.

So far I've created a simple GUI with a button to start/cancel processing in the background (using [parfeval](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html)) and a label to report for progression.

Everything works fine (the code runs in the background and I'm able to handle for background errors or cancellation), the only issue is about reporting background processing progression in client session:

```
function [] = TestBackgroundWorker()
%[
    % Create interface
    fig = figure();
    cuo = onCleanup(@()delete(fig));
    stState = uicontrol('Parent', fig, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.7 0.8 0.2], 'Style', 'text', 'String', 'Ready');
    btnOkCancel = uicontrol('Parent', fig, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.5], 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Go', 'Callback', @(s,e)onOkCancelClicked(fig)); 

    % Backstore
    data = guidata(fig);
    data.bgw = [];
    data.stState = stState;
    data.btnOkCancel = btnOkCancel;
    guidata(fig, data);

    waitfor(fig);   
%]
end
function [] = onBackgroundProgress(fig, ratio, msg)
%[
    % Here I would like to 'BeginInvoke' in client thread
    % to refresh 'ratio/msg' in the GUI.

    % Below code of course doesn't work:
    % 1) It is not synchronized with UI thread
    % 2) It is executed in a session with no display
    data = guidata(fig);
    set(data.stState, 'String', sprintf('%f - %s', ratio, msg));       
%]
end
function [] = onOkCancelClicked(fig)
%[
    % Backstore
    data = guidata(fig);        
    if (~isfield(data, 'bgw'))
        data.bgw = [];        
    end

    if (isempty(data.bgw))

        % Start background work
        set(data.btnOkCancel, 'String', 'Cancel');
        data.bgw = parfeval(@doBackgroundWork, 0, @(r, m)onBackgroundProgress(fig, r, m));
        guidata(fig, data);

        % Wait for error/termination/cancel
        while(true)

            try
                idx = fetchNext(data.bgw, 0.3);
            catch err

                if (~isempty(err.cause) && (strcmp(err.cause{1}.identifier, 'parallel:fevalqueue:ExecutionCancelled')))
                    % Error was due to cancelation
                    uiwait(msgbox('Processing canceled by user!', 'modal'));
                    set(data.btnOkCancel, 'String', 'Go', 'Enable', 'on');
                else
                    % Error real error (TODO: display it in some way)
                    uiwait(msgbox('Processing error!', 'modal'));
                    set(data.btnOkCancel, 'String', 'Go', 'Enable', 'on');
                end

                data.bgw = [];
                guidata(fig, data);
                break;
            end

            if (isempty(idx))
                % Still processing => Enable message pump to read GUI events
                drawnow limitrate; 
            else
                % Processing done
                uiwait(msgbox('Processing done!', 'modal'));
                data.bgw = [];
                guidata(fig, data);
                set(data.btnOkCancel, 'String', 'Go', 'Enable', 'on');
                break;
            end
        end

    else

        % Cancel background work
        set(data.btnOkCancel, 'String', 'Cancelling...', 'Enable', 'off');
        cancel(data.bgw);

    end    
%]
end
function [] = doBackgroundWork(onProgress)
%[
    count = 10;
    for k = 1:count,        
        onProgress((k-1)/count, sprintf('Step %i / %i', k, count)); 
        pause(1);       
    end
%]
end
```

I understand well the issue, that is the callback `onBackgroundProgress` is executed from a session with no display so nothing happens (moreover it is not synchronized with client GUI).

Is there a way to synchronize and pass data to the GUI from the worker (in C# I would have used `BeginInvoke`) ? Probably I'm not using the toolbox in appropriate way to achieve what I would like to have (seems far more oriented toward distributed computation rather than multithreading), is there another way to do it with this toolbox ? ...

**EDIT**

I modified my code to replace [drawnow](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) with a [timer](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) object (*this works*) and tried to use [labSend](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labsend.html) and [labReceive](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labreceive.html) to synchronize UI with background session (*this doesn't work*):

```
%
% PURPOSE:
%
%   Test function to see how to have a responsive GUI while computations
%   are running in the background.
%
% SYNTAX:
%
%   [] = TestBackgroundWorker();
%

%% --- Main routine
function [] = TestBackgroundWorker()
%[
    % Make sure parallel pool is started
    gcp();

    % Create the interface
    % A simple figure with a go/cancel button and a label. 
    fig = figure();
    cuo = onCleanup(@()delete(fig));
    stState = uicontrol('Parent', fig, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.7 0.8 0.2], 'Style', 'text', 'String', 'Ready!');
    btnStartCancel = uicontrol('Parent', fig, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.5], 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Start', 'Callback', @(s,e)onOkCancelClicked(fig)); 

    % Backstore for later use
    data = guidata(fig);    
    data.stState = stState;
    data.btnStartCancel = btnStartCancel;
    guidata(fig, data);

    % Wait until figure is closed
    waitfor(fig);   
%]
end

%% -- Event handler for 'go/cancel' button in the GUI
function [] = onOkCancelClicked(fig)
%[
    % Backstore
    data = guidata(fig);        
    if (~isfield(data, 'bgw'))
        data.bgw = [];        
    end


    % Depending if background process is running or not
    if (isempty(data.bgw))

        % Start background work
        set(data.btnStartCancel, 'String', 'Cancel');
        data.bgw = parfeval(@doBackgroundWork, 0, @(r, m)onBackgroundProgress(fig, r, m));

        % Start timer to monitor bgw
        data.bgwtimer = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedSpacing', 'Period', 0.1, ...
                              'TimerFcn', @(s,e)onBackgroundCheck(fig, data.bgw));

        guidata(fig, data);                          
        start(data.bgwtimer);

    else

        % Cancel background work
        p = gcp('nocreate'); % Make sure parpool is started
        if (~isempty(p))
            cancel(data.bgw);
        end
        set(data.btnStartCancel, 'String', 'Cancelling (please wait)...', 'Enable', 'off');

    end    
%]
end

%% --- Event handlers for monitoring the background worker
function [] = onBackgroundCheck(fig, bgw)
%[    
    try

        idx = fetchNext(bgw, 0.3);
        if (isempty(idx)),

            % Check for messages from the background worker
            if ((numlabs ~= 1) && labProbe)
                data = labReceive();
                onBackgroundProgress(data{:});
            end

        else    
            onBackgroundCompleted(fig);
        end

    catch err

        onBackgroundCompleted(fig, err);

    end    
%]
end
function [] = onBackgroundCompleted(fig, err)
%[
    if (nargin < 2), err = []; end

    if (isempty(err))
        % Normal completion
        uiwait(msgbox('Processing done!', 'Processing', 'help', 'modal'));
    elseif (~isempty(err.cause) && (strcmp(err.cause{1}.identifier, 'parallel:fevalqueue:ExecutionCancelled')))
        % Error was due to cancelation
        uiwait(msgbox('Processing canceled by user!', 'Processing', 'help', 'modal'));
    else
        % Error real error (TODO: display it in some way)
        uiwait(msgbox(sprintf('Processing error: %s', err.message), 'Processing', 'error', 'modal'));                    
    end 

    data = guidata(fig);
    data.bgw = [];
    stop(data.bgwtimer);
    set(data.stState, 'String', 'Ready!');
    set(data.btnStartCancel, 'String', 'Start', 'Enable', 'on');
    guidata(fig, data);        
%]
end

%% --- Event handler for reporting progression status
function [] = onBackgroundProgress(fig, ratio, msg)
%[
    cw = getCurrentWorker();

    if (~isempty(cw))
        % Were are the background thread so send message to the GUI
        % NB: Doing broadcast as I don't know the id of the gui
        labBroadcast(labindex, {fig, ratio, msg });
    else
        % Were are the GUI
        data = guidata(fig);
        set(data.stState, 'String', sprintf('%f - %s', ratio, msg));
    end    
%]
end

%% --- Processing to be performed in the background
function [] = doBackgroundWork(onProgress)
%[
    count = 15;
    for k = 1:count,        
        onProgress((k-1)/count, sprintf('Step %i / %i', k, count)); 
        pause(1);       
    end
%]
end
```

Apparently `labSend` an `labReceive` can only occur between workers but not with the client ... seems to be a dead-end.

Comment: I'm not a PCT expert, but I dont think this will work; `parfeval` executes the function asynchronously on a pool of workers. Locally this runs on separate **processes** (not threads) and remotely on a distributed cluster of computers (think MPI). It is intended to launch functions in the background and fetch results as they become available (one side communication), not a replacement for threads. I dont see how you can communicate from the worker back to the master process to post UI updates. I know of `labSend`/`labReceive` functions, but I'm not sure if they fit in your program structure.

Comment: Thanks @Amro. I updated my code trying to use `labSend/labReceive` but it doesn't work either (see my edited post ... seems `labSend/labReceive` can only occur between `workers` but not with the client) ... Definitely the toolbox is far more *distributed* oriented rather than *multithreaded* oriented, so guess for now it is best to keep my old style [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28378219/684399) to have a responsive GUI.

Comment: That's the impression I get as well; The model offered by PCT is really suited for "submitting jobs" to distributed workers without blocking (with functions like: `createJob`, `parfeval`, `batch`) eventually retrieving results from the promise/deferred object returned. Another approach is that of `parfor`, `spmd`, and `mapreduce` which provide data-parallel style of computation. And finally there's CUDA and GPU computing... All things considered, I find that MATLAB does not lend itself to a multithreaded style of programming (with or without the PCT toolbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only goal is to monitor workers progress, you may want to check out [parfor progress monitor v2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31673-parfor-progress-monitor-v2). It also gives you an idea on how to establish socket connection from workers back to client, which you can use to build more sophisticated UI.

Comment: Yes, I definitely think that so far with PCT this is the best approach for asynchronous instrumentation back to the client. Thanks :)